# Form dynamic attribute changing and submission not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have the following code:

Html:

```
<form action="/" id="mainForm" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="val1" />
    <button id="cmdSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
<button id="cmdSubmit2">Submit 2</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#cmdSubmit2").bind('click', function () {
    Submit2();
});

var Submit2 = function() {
    var form = $("#mainForm").clone();
    form.attr("action", "/testing");

    form.submit();
}
```

What I'm trying to do is dynamically change the action attribute of a form with javascript and then submit it (to a different url).

What I expect to happen (in JsFiddle) is that clicking the submit button should load the jsfiddle home page, and clicking the `Submit2` button should load a 404 page since the `/testing` url doesn't exist.

This works fine in chrome (28.0.1500.95), but does not work in Firefox (23.0.1) or IE for that matter(10.0.9200.16660).

None of these browser show any errors in the console either - I'm stumped. Any ideas?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansfield/WRP3u/2/)

EDIT: I do actually have to clone the form, forgot to mention that. Also, this works fine in Safari (v5.1.7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow insert it in the DOM :

```
function Submit2() {
    var form = $("#mainForm").clone();
    form.attr("action", "/testing");
    form.hide().appendTo('body');

    form.submit();
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WRP3u/7/)

Works for me (FF 23.0)

Comment: Oddly enough, the fiddle didn't work in IE but when I applied this fix to my actual program it worked fine in all browsers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `clone()` the form. Try this:

```
var Submit2 = function() {
    var form = $("#mainForm");
    form.prop("action", "/testing");    
    form.submit();
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WRP3u/3/)

Comment: Actually, I do have another requirement to clone the form (I should have mentioned that). Sorry!